# check a record for Duplicates Records, Before Creating New Records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to this site and new to vba code.  Another user posted this question and the answer code seemed to be the code I was looking for. I want to check several fields for duplicate data, flag a message and go to the record.  I was hoping this code would do that. Except when I add my own fields to check I get error code 3077 - syntax error and I am not sure how to fix it.  any help would be appreciated.  The line highted for this error is the 3rd line down.  I am using access 2010. I am not sure how to link to the question but was advised I should ask a new question regarding my problem.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "[ID] <> " & Me.ID & " AND [TitleText] = " & Me.TitleText & " AND [UnitCode] = " & Me.UnitCode & " AND  [AcademicYear] = " & Me.AcademicYear & " AND    [Titleofchapterjournalarticle] = " & Me.Titleofchapterjournalarticle
    If Not rst.NoMatch Then
        Cancel = True
        If MsgBox("A record matching these fields already exist", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Me.Undo
            DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "[ID] = " & rst("ID")
        End If
    End If
    rst.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: @mehow What is the secret behind adding `excel-vba` tag in every question ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean that the fourth line down is the one highlighted, `rst.FindFirst...`.

If that is the case, there is a syntax error in your `FindFirst` string. It could be that your  *TitleText* or *Titleofchapterjournalarticle* fields contained spaces or logic code (OR, AND). To prevent this, surround any string type fields with ' (single quote) inside the string.

The final result will look like:

```
rst.FindFirst "[ID] <> " & Me.ID & _
 " AND [TitleText] = '" & Me.TitleText & _
 "' AND [UnitCode] = " & Me.UnitCode & _
 " AND [AcademicYear] = " & Me.AcademicYear & _
 " AND [Titleofchapterjournalarticle] = '" & Me.Titleofchapterjournalarticle & "'"
```

Comment: thank you, thats great. It has worked, I just need to trouble shoot the DoCmd, to get it to go to the specific record. Cheers!

Comment: @Janeyg `DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acFirst, "ID = " & rst.("ID")` worked for me on my test form.

Comment: No problem. If my post answer solved your problem, please pick it. Thanks!