# Why can't this VBA Excel code read duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
    r = 11

Do While Not tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = "0"

    If tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 1, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 2, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 3, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 4, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 5, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 6, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 7, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 8, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 9, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 10, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 11, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 12, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 13, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 14, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 15, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 16, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 17, 2) Or tgtWSheet.Cells(r, 2) = tgtWSheet.Cells(r + 18, 2) Then

        MsgBox "Duplicate Record Found!"
        Exit Sub

    Else

        r = r + 1

    End If

Loop
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not feature any body text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try "And" instead of "Or". The reason is because of a logic issue. I think someone has asked this question before. You can refer to the following post for some help.

[check a record for Duplicates Records, Before Creating New Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379981/check-a-record-for-duplicates-records-before-creating-new-records)

Anyway, his chain of thought is to give a name to the column and check if there is any duplicate in the row using the following formula.

```
rst.FindFirst "[ID] <> " & Me.ID & _
 " AND [TitleText] = '" & Me.TitleText & _
 "' AND [UnitCode] = " & Me.UnitCode & _
 " AND [AcademicYear] = " & Me.AcademicYear & _
 " AND [Titleofchapterjournalarticle] = '" & Me.Titleofchapterjournalarticle & "'"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for  that. i'm still new in programming...this program is to upload in AS400.but before that, the program should check first for duplicates...thanks for helping.