# Where is the error in my VBA code that read duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have an Excel file. In column B row 11 is my product number range up to 100 rows. The code should find duplicate values in the column B. My code is like this:

```
Dim tgtWB As Workbook
Dim tgtWS As Worksheet
Dim LstRow As Long

LstRow = range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

r = 11
   For i = 11 To LstRow
       Do until tgWS.Range("B" & i) = "0"
        If tgtWS.Range("B" & i) = tgtWS.Range("B" & i+1) Then
          msgbox " Duplicate/s found! " & vbCrLf & tgtWS.Range("B" &i).value
          exit sub
        else
            r = r+1
        end if
       Loop
       Next
```

I just inserted the `Do until` because the program would stop reading
    duplicate values if values in column B are blank or zero(0). And
    the code compares only the column B Row 11 and 12.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to `Set` **tgtWs**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vba excel code...i want to know why it can't read duplicates?...need your help guys...TIA :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592902/vba-excel-code-i-want-to-know-why-it-cant-read-duplicates-need-your-help-g)

Answer (score 0):

Please examine this to see if it can be adapted to your needs:

```
Sub John()
    Dim tgtWS As Worksheet
    Dim LstRow As Long

    Set tgtWS = ActiveSheet
    LstRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 11 To LstRow
        If tgtWS.Range("B" & i) = "0" Then Exit Sub
        If tgtWS.Range("B" & i) = tgtWS.Range("B" & i + 1) Then
            MsgBox " Duplicate/s found! " & vbCrLf & tgtWS.Range("B" & i).Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It will find the first set of duplicates *(if they are consecutive records)* 
You would need a double loop if the dups are not consecutive